# Onclick and data-target

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I am working with asp. I have a button which opens a modal to edit a recipe. The modal appears but it doesn't call the function I want to activate with the click.

I have tried these two lines:

```
<!---<asp:Button ID="btnEditar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-block" Text="EDITAR" OnClick="btnEditar_Click" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal1" />--->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-block" data-toggle="modal" Width="200px" runar="server" OnServerClick="btnEditar_Click" data-target="#exampleModal1" >EDITAR</button>
```

In code:

```
Protected Sub btnEditar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim var1 = "TemperaturaProducto"
        Dim var2 = "TemperaturaCamisa"
        Dim var3 = "VelocidadAgitacion"
        Dim var4 = "IntensidadAgitacion"
        Dim var5 = "Tiempo"
        Dim var6 = "FindePaso"
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RECETAConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim query As String = "select * from " & Module1.Rnom.ToString & "_V" & Module1.verc.ToString

        Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                    Using ds As New DataSet()
                        sda.Fill(ds)
                        var1 = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(var1).ToString
                        var2 = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(var2).ToString
                        var3 = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(var3).ToString
                        var4 = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(var4).ToString
                        var5 = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(var5).ToString
                        var6 = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(var6).ToString
                        'grupo = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Grupo").ToString
                        'Config.usuario.Value = Config.Equals[]
                        'Context.Items.Add("usuario", usuario)
                        'Module1.usuario = usuario

                        'GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                        'GridView1.DataBind()
                        'GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(1)
                        'GridView1.DataBind()

                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        txtTempProd.Text = var1
        txtTempCam.Text = var2
        txtVelAgi.Text = var3
        txtIntAgi.Text = var4
        txtTiempoMinutos.Text = var5
    End Sub
```

My intention is that the modal does not disappear when the function is activated.

Comment: I think the problem is that after executing the function the site master starts again so it deletes the modal. I can't find a way not to run site master again.

Comment: What is being used to show the modal dialog? You might find it simpler to create a service on the server which supplies the data and use AJAX in the client to query that service to populate the dialog. (Also, for production code you should avoid using `*` in an SQL query: give it the column names in the order that you want them retrieved - the database is free to return the columns in any order it likes at any time.)

Comment: Holy SQL Injection issues, Batman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, you don't show or mention or share what kind of modal dialog system you are using. (And there are boatloads of them to choose from).

***This example code assumes jQuery, and also jQuery.UI is installed and available.***

The issue of course is if you have a button, and when clicked it pops open a dialog? Well, if you THEN post-back to run some server-side code, then you get a whole new web page re-load, and thus your dialog popup will be gone.

And then there is the second case in which you have a popup dialog, and you click a asp.net button (server-side button) in that dialog. Once again, when you click such a button, you again get a post-back, and thus once again the result is a whole browser re-load, and thus once again, any popup dialog will close. In some cases, you may well want the dialog to stay open.

So, there are 2 different cases here.
However, let’s go with the second case.
So, logic:

You click a button (server side).
Load and get some data – fill out some controls, AND THEN pop the dialog.

For this example, in place of a button click, let’s use a combo box.
It will post-back. (Just like a button click would)

We then use our code to load up the controls, and THEN pop our dialog.

So, our markup will have a dropdown list (to select a hotel).

That markup:

```
        <h3>Select Hotel to Edit</h3>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboHotel" runat="server"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName"
            AutoPostBack="true"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboHotel_SelectedIndexChanged" 
             Width="261px"                
            >
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

And in our page load event, we load up the above combo box

this code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ' this is the REAL first page load
        ' load up default controls, combo box etc.

        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA 
            ORDER BY HotelName"

        cboHotel.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)
        cboHotel.DataBind()
        cboHotel.Items.Insert(0, "Select Hotel")

    End If

End Sub
```

OK, so that takes care of our combo box.

So, right below the combo box, let's add a "div" area, and drop in a bunch of controls. This could be your example, or whatever.

However, whatever we drop into this "div" area is going to be our popup area.

So, say some controls to edit the hotel, like this:

```
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id="editarea" style="display: none" class="Ebox">

            <div style="float: left" class="iForm">
                <br />
                
                <label>Hotel Name</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" Width="280"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />

                <label>City</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tCity" runat="server" f="City" Width="140"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />

                <label>Province</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tProvince" runat="server" Width="75"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />

            </div>
            <div style="float: left; margin-left: 20px" class="iForm">
                <label>Description</label>
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" Width="400" TextMode="MultiLine"
                    Height="130px" f="Description"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive"  runat="server" style="margin-right:5px" /><b>Active</b> 

                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBalcony" runat="server" style="margin-left:20px;margin-right:5px" /><b>Has Balcony</b>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>


            <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdSave" runat="server" CssClass="btn myshadow"
                OnClick="cmdSave_Click">
                        <span class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-lg"> Save</span>
            </asp:LinkButton>


            <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdCancel" runat="server" class="btn myshadow" Style="margin-left: 15px">
                        <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left fa-lg"> Back/Cancel</span>
            </asp:LinkButton>

            <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" class="btn myshadow" Style="margin-left: 15px">
                        <span class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"> Delete</span>
            </asp:LinkButton>


        </div>
```

Ok, so now we need to fill out the above controls.
(Note that during development, use display: normal, and ONLY once you have the layout how you want, then as last step, change the style of edit area and use "display: none"

So, now our code to load up the controls. (The combo box selected changed index event).

```
Protected Sub cboHotel_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA 
                                 WHERE ID = @ID")

    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cboHotel.SelectedItem.Value

    Dim rstData As DataTable = MyRstP(cmdSQL)

    Dim OneRow = rstData.Rows(0)

    txtHotel.Text = OneRow("HotelName")
    tCity.Text = OneRow("City")
    tProvince.Text = OneRow("Province")
    txtNotes.Text = OneRow("Description")
    chkActive.Checked = OneRow("Active")
    chkBalcony.Checked = OneRow("Balcony")

    ' now pop the dialog
    Dim sJava As String = "mypop()"

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType, "my java", sJava, True)


End Sub
```

And we also do need one JavaScript routine.

So, right after the edit area div, we have this code:

```
    <script>

        function mypop() {

            myDialog = $("#editarea")

            myDialog.dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                appendTo: "form",
                closeText: "",
                width:"840px",
                title: "Edit Hotel",
                dialogClass: "dialogWithDropShadow"
            })

            myDialog.dialog('open')
        }

    </script>
```

So, the effect and result looks like this:

[image]

And, the save button code look?

```
Protected Sub cmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA 
                                 WHERE ID = @ID")

    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cboHotel.SelectedItem.Value

    Dim rstData As DataTable = MyRstP(cmdSQL)

    Dim OneRow = rstData.Rows(0)

    OneRow("HotelName") = txtHotel.Text
    OneRow("City") = tCity.Text
    OneRow("Province") = tProvince.Text
    OneRow("Description") = txtNotes.Text
    OneRow("Active") = chkActive.Checked
    OneRow("Balcony") = chkBalcony.Checked

    SaveData(rstData, cmdSQL)


End Sub
```

So, looking close at above?

I used a few "helper" routines. Add these to your Module1 "general" code. These routines can be used over and over for each web page you create.

These general routines (say in Module1) are:

```
Public Function GetConStr() As String

    Return My.Settings.TEST4
    ' ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RECETAConnectionString").ConnectionString

End Function



Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable
    ' general get any data from SQL
    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(GetConstr)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            rstData.TableName = strSQL
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData
End Function

Public Function MyRstP(cmdSQL As SqlCommand) As DataTable
    ' general get any data from SQL command
    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(GetConstr)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function

Public Sub MyRstPE(cmdSQL As SqlCommand)
    ' General execute sql - no return of data

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(GetConStr)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub

Public Sub SaveData(rstData As DataTable, cmdSQL As SqlCommand)

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(GetConStr)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim daU As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
            da.Update(rstData)

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

So, not a lot of code, but those routines are like "gold", since the code behind on a web page now becomes very much like working in VB6, or like working in MS-Access. Use the above design for all of your code.

## Part two, and post-backs inside of dialog

So, the first part shows how to load up some data, and display a dialog. However, the question was how to allow standard asp.net buttons to work inside of the popup dialog, and have the dialog NOT close.

The simple solution is to use an update panel. Placement of the update panel is important here, and it is to be placed just inside of the popup div.

So, this format

```
   div
       update panel
   end div
```

So, let's move the combo box into that popup div. We remove code that pops the dialog on selecting of a hotel. However, the save button will now save the data, so after saving, we clear the controls, and re-set the combo box back to "Select a Hotel".

The save button and the combo box will trigger post-backs, but note how the popup dialog remains open.

So, our markup now becomes this:

First, the button to show the popup

```
    <div style="padding:35px; margin-left: 40px;">
        <asp:Button ID="cmdShowPop" runat="server" Text="Show Pop"
            OnClientClick="mypop();return false"                
            />
```

And now we move all of the previous markup, including the combo box (dropdown list) to inside of the content template like this

[image]

The close button before had no code (but did cause a post-back which closed the dialog). That button code now has to close the dialog, and is thus this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="cmdCancel" runat="server" class="btn myshadow" 
    Style="margin-left: 15px"
    OnClientClick="$('#editarea').dialog('close');return false;">
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left fa-lg"> Close</span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

The result is now a popup dialog that can survive post-backs, and looks like this:

[image]

The change to the combo box code simple removes the popup dialog code, and is now this:

```
Protected Sub cboHotel_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA 
                                 WHERE ID = @ID")

    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cboHotel.SelectedItem.Value

    Dim rstData As DataTable = MyRstP(cmdSQL)
    Dim OneRow = rstData.Rows(0)

    txtHotel.Text = OneRow("HotelName")
    tCity.Text = OneRow("City")
    tProvince.Text = OneRow("Province")
    txtNotes.Text = OneRow("Description")
    chkActive.Checked = OneRow("Active")
    chkBalcony.Checked = OneRow("Balcony")

    '' now pop the dialog
    'Dim sJava As String = "mypop()"
    'ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType, "my java", sJava, True)

End Sub
```

So, you can inside of the popup div insert an update panel, and this will prevent the dialog from closing due to standard button post-backs. Only additional part is to have a close button to close the dialog as per above.